# Plotting the maximum as a function of a parameter

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I have defined a function called `xd` as shown below:

```
xa[δx_, δy_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_,P_] := NIntegrate[
2*e1*e2*Exp[-((x - δx)^2 + (y - δy)^2)/W^2]*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/L^2]
, {x, 0, r}
, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}
, MinRecursion -> 10
, MaxRecursion -> 20
, PrecisionGoal -> 3
, WorkingPrecision -> 40
]

xb[δx_, δy_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_,P_] := NIntegrate[
2*e1*e2*Exp[-((x - δx)^2 + (y - δy)^2)/W^2]*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/L^2]
, {x,-r,0}
, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}
, MinRecursion -> 10
, MaxRecursion -> 20
, PrecisionGoal -> 3
, WorkingPrecision -> 40
]


xd[δx_, δy_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_,P_] := xa[δx, δy, e1, e2, W, L,
r,P]-xb[δx, δy, e1, e2, W, L,r,P]
```

Now, I only wish to vary the parameters `δx` and `L`. For a given value of `δx`, I am interested in the value of `L` at which `xd` is maximum. How can I obtain a plot of the value of `L` at which `xd` is maximised for a given value of `δx`, as a function of `δx`?

Comment: What values are the other parameters taking? (I'm assuming you're not looking for an analytical solution since you're using `NIntegrate`)

Comment: δy=0,  e1=783,  e2=5000,  W=3*10^-4,  r=3.9*10^-3, P=19*10^-3

Answer (score 1):

Do as much integration analytically as you can.

```
integrand = 2*e1*e2*Exp[-((x - \[Delta]x)^2 + (y - \[Delta]y)^2)/W^2]*
            Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/L^2];

int1[x_, \[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_, r_, P_] = 
       Integrate[integrand, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}]

(*   (E^(-(x^2/L^2) - (x - \[Delta]x)^2/W^2 - \[Delta]y^2/(
      L^2 + W^2)) e1 e2 L Sqrt[\[Pi]] W (Erf[((L^2 + W^2) Sqrt[
      r^2 - x^2] - L^2 \[Delta]y)/(L W Sqrt[L^2 + W^2])] + 
      Erf[((L^2 + W^2) Sqrt[r^2 - x^2] + L^2 \[Delta]y)/(
      L W Sqrt[L^2 + W^2])]))/Sqrt[L^2 + W^2]   *)

{\[Delta]y = 0, e1 = 783, e2 = 5000, W = 3*10^-4, r = 39*10^-4, P = 19*10^-3};
```

Second step now is numerical integration, since there is no analytical integral

```
xa[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_?NumericQ, r_, P_] := 
      NIntegrate[int1[x, \[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r, P], {x, 0, r}, 
            MinRecursion -> 6]

xb[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_?NumericQ, r_, P_] := 
NIntegrate[int1[x, \[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r, P], {x, -r, 0}, 
            MinRecursion -> 6]

xd[\[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, e1_, e2_, W_, L_?NumericQ, r_, P_] := 
xa[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r, P] - 
xb[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r, P]
```

A Log-Plot shows, maximum of xd is always reached at L -> Infinity

```
LogPlot[xd[7 10^-4, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r, P], {L, 0, 10^-2}, 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can show how the limit of xd at L -> Infinity varies with Deltax

```
ListLogPlot[
   Table[{\[Delta]x, 
      NLimit[xd[\[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, e1, e2, W, L, r, P], 
         L -> \[Infinity], Method -> SequenceLimit]}, {\[Delta]x,10^-4, 
         4 10^-3, 10^-4}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a step towards it. If I get the full answer I will edit this code.

I would try first to evaluate the integral using _?NumericQ like:

```
xa[δx_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  2*e1*e2*Exp[-((x - δx)^2 + (y - δy)^2)/W^2]*
   Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/L^2], {x, 0, 
   r}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}, MinRecursion -> 10,
   MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

xb[δx_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  2*e1*e2*Exp[-((x - δx)^2 + (y - δy)^2)/W^2]*
   Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/L^2], {x, -r, 
   0}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}, MinRecursion -> 10,
   MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

Still we get very tiny values as the integral for example:

```
In[32]:= xa[2, 2]

Out[32]= 2.84267753118299090297623523215*10^-19226780
```

The corresponding xb value is yet to be evaluated. Do you have rough ideas for values of δx and L which lead to reasonable output ?

Comment: Something like  δx=10^-4 and L=4*10^-4 should be reasonable.